# error: cannot find symbol: IonicCordovaCommon.java:61

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 app that we have been using in production. I just did a new clone of the repo and tried to build the android version. It fails with:

```
com/ionicframework/common/IonicCordovaCommon.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
assetManager = cordova.getContext().getAssets();
                          ^
  symbol:   method getContext()
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface

  src/com/ionicframework/common/IonicCordovaCommon.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    Context c = cordova.getContext();
                       ^
  symbol:   method getContext()
```

I did not change anything in the code base -- and it was working well a few hours ago before the clone of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a plugin. The package.json had the following spec:

```
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.3.0",
```

Turns out the latest version of the plugin is not compatible. To fix, just change to

```
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.3.0",
```

That is stick to 5.3.0 -- and not later version.

Remove plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic
```

Add older version

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic@5.3.0
```

This fails with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic@5.3.0
Variable(s) missing (use: --variable APP_ID=value --variable CHANNEL_NAME=value).
```

To fix remove platform android and add again.

```
cordova platform rm android;  cordova platform add android@6.4
```

Once done, the build using

```
cordova build android
```

and see it succeed.